# Why does the following code only have space complexity O(N)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

This is taken straight from Cracking the coding interview by Gayle Lakmaan McDowell.

She lists the following code:

```
 int f(int n) {
 if(n<=1){
   return 1;
  }
 return f(n-1) + f(n-1);
}
```

She has an articulate explanation about why the time complexity is O(2^n), but why is the space complexity here only O(N)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The space complexity is taking in account the call stack usage. The function will call itself `O(N)` times before returning, so the call stack will be `O(N)` deep.

**Update (thanks @MatthewWetmore):**

To clarify, the two recursive calls in the `f(n-1) + f(n-1);` expression are not executed in parallel. First one call is completed consuming the linear stack usage, and then the second one, consuming the same stack size. So no doubling of the space is happening, which is different from the running-time consumption (which is obviously accumulated each call).

Comment: but the recursive function is called twice, won't that result in two additional stacks?

Comment: @Django the constant factor is not taken in account in the big-O notation, so `O(2N) = O(N)`.

Comment: Why wouldn't the space complexity be O(2^N)?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: There's no inherent parallelism there.  The left side of the operation will evaluate recursively before the right side starts.  Space is exactly O(N), right, not O(2N)?

Comment: @MatthewWetmore Ah I see now, that's why it's O(N), thanks both!

Comment: @MatthewWetmore Right. Now I think my answer is oversimplified. I should add something to it..

Answer (score 0):

It uses that much space in system stack for function call 
like F(5) will call F(4) which wil call F(3)

F(5)->F(4)->F(3)->F(2)->F(1)->return value will close function in reverse sequence

so for calculation this space is allocated in stack that is for F(5) 5 stack space so for F(n) , space will be O(N)

Answer (score 0):

The O notation is an asymtotic notation. This means that the notation states that the time to complete the algorithm would never surpass certain limit and it can go below but this is not specified, it is bounded. 
The time complexity of an algorithm depends on the size of the input. This can be {1} an input of one number or {1,2} an input double the size of the previous input. That is what the n means O(n). This means the algorithm has linear complexity that means the time to complete the algorithm would be n * some constant or C * n.
You may ask yourself how do we determine C well that is why we use aymptotic notation we can omit the exact value of C, this is useful because we might see an algorithm can have a C that varies depending on the order of the input or some other condition. You might see best case scnearios and worst case scenarios where the complexity is Cn and the worst is Cnlogn in this case we say the algorithm has O(nlogn) complexity this is because we take the worst case scenario as the boundary. In this case we still omit the C and we omit the best case scenario Cn. You might consider reading an algorithm book for more information like the art of computer programming book 1, or [Algorithms by Robert Sedgewick](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032157351X). The book by Sedgewick uses Java and is very accesible.

Space complexity works the same way but this time we are talking about memory space, there is a technique called dynamic programming and this technique stores previous results so you can use them later as solutions to subproblems. That way we skip the time it takes to make the calculation to the subproblem many times, however the amount of memory needed to solve the problem increases the classic example is the [Change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem). You store many solutions and the space it takes in system memoy increases. The problem has linear space complexity because the amount of memory needed to solve the problem behaves as a function Cn.

As an example this function uses n which can be said to be one space in memory, the 1 constant is another so we can say the space in memory would be 1 + n; in this case we say the linear function has a displacement a the linear function is Cn + a where C = 1 and a = 1. Still a linear funtion. The n comes from the recursion as we will need n spaces in memory to store the n numbers as the recursion goes all the way down to 1. so for example lets say n = 3.

The first time we have 3 in memory as it goes down the recursion we store 2 in memory and last 1,  we can say 1 is already in memory or not as the space where the 1 resides might be on stack or on heap. That is why we use O notation this is dependent on the architecture implementation. So while sometimes the complexity can be 1+n it can also be n but saying O(n) we cover both cases.

Also if you have doubts about the line:

```
f(n-1) + f(n-1);
```

Depending on architecture you may have a stack or you can send them to main memory(No example of this architecture comes to mind) and have a garbage collector clean the references as it goes out of scope, it will still be linear space as you store 3 * 2, 2 * 2, 1 * 2. In this case it will be 2n+1 or 2n. Still linear. But I doubt you see anything like this most likey you will hava a stack and as soon as the recursion return it will start popping all the variables from the stack, using at most 1+n or n+1.